# How to compare time-series predictions between XGB and Random Forest

Tags: python, random-forest, xgboost

I have time series forecasting assignment, and I used a random forest regressor and XGBoost to predict the future price.

I would like to ask what kind of code or what I should do as a conclusion assignment to choose which result prediction more better.

[XBG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMMRV.png) and [Randomforest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EvfO.png)

any help for a link or share code much appreciates it because I try to google but still can't find the solution and it's near my dateline.

Comment: [stats.se] is typically a better place for algorithm selection questions. Note that software recommendation questions are categorically off-topic on Stack Overflow; see #3 in the "some questions are still off-topic" section of https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. For discussion of what questions [stats.se] accepts, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic -- and see https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12/how-should-we-deal-with-obvious-homework-questions discussing how they handle homework questions.

Answer (score 0):

Diebold-Mariano Test is one of the statistical methods to compare forecasting predictions. It identifies forecast accuracy equivalence for 2 sets of predictions.

[Diebold-Mariano Test Implementation from Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/code/jorgesandoval/xgboost-vs-lightgbm-using-diebold-mariano-test)